# How to speed up Magento 2 development process?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, development, speedoptimization

I find the development of Magento 2 technical solutions (plugins, themes, etc.) very slow. If I do some JS changes, I need to redeploy the static content each time, if I do some changes in the PHP code (not constructor-related changes), I need to re-compile in different situations.

All this process of running CLI commands is taking time, a lot of time, even if I have the developer mode enabled, the cache disabled, and so on.

What "dev set up" are you using to speed up the process??
Is there some trick I need to make to speed up the process??

Looking forward to seeing your thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of thing for development but some of them in my mind now.

I listed as below

**1.** Always Work in Developer Mode

**2.** Never run Deploy Command in Developer. it will not generate symlink it will generate copy of files so css and js never get instant effect.

**3.** Make sure all cache enable. and you can perform cache clean command for get effect xml file or admin related changes.

**4.** If you change anything in constructor then you can delete that file from "generated" folder. it will quick way to get effect instead of run compile command

**5.** You can work with js/css/html file in same way like delete from pub and it will regenerated instead of run full deploy command.

Note( BTW in developer mode you don't need to run deploy command ever)